# How to match one column of dataframe to another based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to take the efficiency values from the first dataframe (2022) and put it into the second dataframe (2023), matching it on all the qualitative columns: "Country", "State", "District", "Month", "Type" and "Name"

First dataframe:

| Country | State | District | Year | Month | Type | Name | No of Jobs | Hours | Efficiency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | AL | A | 2022 | 1 | New | AA | 54 | 209 | 4 |
| USA | AK | B | 2022 | 2 | New | BB | 65 | 382 | 6 |
| USA | AZ | C | 2022 | 3 | Old | CC | 78 | 838 | 11 |
| USA | CA | D | 2022 | 4 | New | DD | 43 | 632 | 15 |
| USA | MD | E | 2022 | 5 | Old | EE | 24 | 194 | 8 |
| USA | ME | F | 2022 | 6 | Old | FF | 54 | 283 | 5 |

Second dataframe:

| Country | State | District | Year | Month | Type | Name | No of Jobs | Hours | Efficiency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | AL | A | 2023 | 1 | New | AA | 76 | 546 | 7 |
| USA | AK | B | 2023 | 2 | New | BB | 52 | 301 | 6 |
| USA | AZ | C | 2023 | 3 | Old | CC | 41 | 455 | 11 |
| USA | CA | D | 2023 | 4 | New | DD | 50 | 301 | 6 |
| USA | MD | E | 2023 | 5 | Old | EE | 85 | 537 | 6 |
| USA | ME | F | 2023 | 6 | Old | FF | 42 | 889 | 21 |

Desired output:

| Country | State | District | Year | Month | Type | Name | No of Jobs | Hours | Efficiency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | AL | A | 2023 | 1 | New | AA | 76 | 294 | 4 |
| USA | AK | B | 2023 | 2 | New | BB | 52 | 306 | 6 |
| USA | AZ | C | 2023 | 3 | Old | CC | 41 | 440 | 11 |
| USA | CA | D | 2023 | 4 | New | DD | 50 | 735 | 15 |
| USA | MD | E | 2023 | 5 | Old | EE | 85 | 687 | 8 |
| USA | ME | F | 2023 | 6 | Old | FF | 42 | 220 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the `merge` function in `pandas` to match rows in one `dataframe` with another based on multiple columns. Here is the code below, just replace `df1` and `df2` with the actual names of your `dataframes`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1_selected = df1[['Country', 'State', 'District', 'Month', 'Type', 'Name', 'Efficiency']].rename(columns={'Efficiency': 'Efficiency_2022'})

df_merged = pd.merge(df2, df1_selected,  on=['Country', 'State', 'District', 'Month', 'Type', 'Name'], how='left')

df_merged['Efficiency'] = df_merged['Efficiency_2022']

df_merged = df_merged.drop(columns=['Efficiency_2022'])

df_merged
```